# ¿Cómo obtener el número de día, sabiendo la semana y año en c#?

Tags: c#

Hola que tal compañeros tengo la siguiente duda que no he podido resolver, en mi código asp tengo 2 `DropDownList`: uno contiene la semana, otro el año. Ahora en mi código en c# tengo una función que recibe la semana, el año y el día, quiero que esta función me regrese el número de día, mes y año con estos parámetros, he investigado sobre fechas pero no he podido realizarlo.

Ejemplo

```
semana = 43;
anio = 2017;
dia = 4;// (Jueves)
public datetime fecha(int semana, int anio, int dia){
    //calcular  fecha

    return 2017/10/19;
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme saludos.

Comment: Hola Ernesto, por favor coloca el código que tienes hasta el momento, lo que has puesto es un pseudocódigo, no es c# válido

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Quieres obtener el total de dias que ha transcurrido en la fecha dada?

Comment: Quiere obtener la fecha que corresponde al día Jueves de la semana 43 del año 2017 en su ejemplo

Comment: y que probaste para calcular el jueves? ni siquiera una prueba a mano para llegar a esa fecha?

Comment: Parece un problema matemático en lugar de un problema de programación.

Comment: exacto quiero obtener el dia que corresponde al dia jueves de la semana 43 del año 2017 como menciona @CarlosMuñoz, lo que puse fue un ejemplo de lo que me gustaria obtener con los valores dados, obviamente esos valores varian dependiendo de la semana el año y el dia de la semana que me proporciona el usuario

Comment: La respuesta depende de cómo defines el comienzo de la primera semana del año. Por ejemplo, algunos dirían que simplemente comienza con el primer día del año sin importar en qué día de la semana cae, mientras que otros lo definen como el primer domingo (o tal vez lunes) del año. ¿Cómo lo defines tu?

Comment: Según el resultado debe ser el primer día del año.

Comment: @Carlos: De ser así creo que el resultado sería mas bien Oct 26, a menos que `semana = 1` es en realidad la segunda semana, y `semana = 0` indica la primera. En fin, creo que OP debería aclarar bien esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas Ernesto,

Te dejo una función que hace lo que pides con la explicación del código:

```
    using System.Globalization;
    public DateTime ObtenerFecha(int anio, int dia, int semana)
    {
        //Declaramos una fecha para el 1 de enero del año que hemos pasado
        DateTime fecha = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(anio), 1, 1);
        //Miramos los días que se le tienen que sumar a la primera fecha para tener el primer día deseado
        //Convertimos el día deseado (que se pasa como int (4 = Jueves)) al tipo Enum DayOfWeek
        int daysOffset = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), dia.ToString()) - fecha.DayOfWeek;

        //Añadimos los días a la primera fecha, y así ya tenemos el primer dia deseado
        DateTime primerDia = fecha.AddDays(daysOffset);
        //Obtenemos el calendario de la cultura local
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        //Obtenemos el numero de la semana del día que tenemos calculado
        int primeraSemana = cal.GetWeekOfYear(primerDia, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);


        var numSemana = semana;
        //Si la primeraSemana <= 1 entonces le restamos 1 a numSemana para obtener la fecha correcta
        if (primeraSemana <= 1)
        {
            numSemana -= 1;
        }
        //Multiplicamos el numero de semanas * 7 que son los días y lo añadimos a la fecha, de ésta forma ya tenemos la fecha entera con el día deseado
        DateTime result = primerDia.AddDays(numSemana * 7);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hola que tal si muchas gracias estuve jugando con fechas y logre hacerlo asi  DateTime t = new DateTime(anio, 1, 1);
        t = t.AddDays((semana * 7) - 7 + dia), aunque tu codigo lo veo mas estructurado gracias por el aporte y ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Cabe mencionar que para hacer correr tu código requieres la referencia a `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: @ErnestoZarateJurado El código que he puesto está adaptado para que funcione en cualquier localización, al final es lo mismo que me muestras en el comentario, pero tiene en cuenta la zona horaria de donde estés ejecutando el código ya que pueden variar las fechas dependiendo de dónde estés.

Answer (score 2):

Rapidamente, puedes hacer algo asi (no es optimo, solo soluciona el problema):

```
using System.Globalization;



DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
int semana = 43;
int anio = 2017;
DayOfWeek dia = DayOfWeek.Thursday;// (Jueves)
bool encontre = false;
//armar una fecha
DateTime fechainicio = new DateTime(anio, 1, 1);
//le resto uno ya que sumo al inicio del while
fechainicio = fechainicio.AddDays(-1);
while (!encontre)
    {
        fechainicio = fechainicio.AddDays(1);
        if (cal.GetWeekOfYear(fechainicio,dfi.CalendarWeekRule,DayOfWeek.Monday) == semana)
        {
            //es la semana que corresponde, ahora chequeo el dia
            if (cal.GetDayOfWeek(fechainicio) == dia)
                {
                    encontre = true;
                }

        }
    }
Console.WriteLine(fechainicio.ToShortDateString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Fijate que lo que hice fue iniciar una fecha al primer dia del año, y luego iterar hasta encontrar la semana que buscaba, y dentro de ella el dia que queria.

Seguramente hay funciones mas comodas para hacer esto, pero dado que no probaste mucho mas, esto lo hace. Ten cuidado al inicializar el canlendario, ya que tiene ciertas particularidades (como contar las semanas, y ese tipo de cosas que no aclaraste en tu pregunta).